# What actually happens to the volume of a gas in an isolated system?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws, pressure

In an isolated system with adiabatic walls in which gas is filled what exactly happens? How do we define the volume of a gas here? Is volume of 1 mole of gas  present in that inelastic container the same as the volume of say 5 moles of the same gas in that container?

Comment: Sure.  What did you think?

Comment: By definition, gasses fill the volume of their container.

Comment: Do you think, if there were originally 5 moles and 4 moles were spent, there would be 1 mol in the 1/5 of the container volume, and rest would be vacuum ?

Comment: @Poutnik, that would break the second law of thermodynamics !

Comment: @Edison Yau Thinking is not bound by laws of thermodynamic.  More precisily, thinking is, but its conclusions are not :-)

Comment: What I actually thought was since the gas is confined to the system(container) shouldn't the volume occupied by 5 moles and 1 mole of the same gas be the same?

Comment: It is. Why it should not be ? It does not matter, if the system is isolated or not. Gases always occupy all volume they can, as fast as they can.

Comment: @Poutnik is correct if you want the simple reason to this, it's actually related to the dispersion of the energy, specifically the potential energy stored in the intermolecular forces. It's related to entropy.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of a gas is based on the pressure, temperature and number of moles.
According to the ideal gas law :

$PV = nRT$

Where P is the pressure, V is the volume, n is the number of moles, R is a gas constant and T is the temperature.

In your case, the volume of both containers is the same, thus the volume of both gases are equal. However, assuming the temperature of the system is constant, the pressure that the gases exist must be different :

V, T, R = Constants -> $ n \propto P$

Therefore, the pressure of the container with 5 moles is five times of that of the one with 1 mole.

To actually make a fair comparison of the volumes of both moles of gases, the pressure that they are in need to be the same. So, if 5 moles of the gas is placed in a container that has 5 times the volume of the one with one mole, the pressure would be the same but the volume would be different (5:1).

Here is a helpful video for you to understand the concept: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxUS1K7xu30